# how do i change escape vim key binding to jk or something else in vscode. NB. vscode not vim editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

resources available on the web are only touching on vim editor. I am new to vim and I don't want to mess with my workspace settings. How do I go about changingg or keeping esc and adding jk as an optional key binding to leave insert mode in Vim in Vscode.

Comment: Are you referring to the Vim extension in vscode?

Answer (score 4):

You should change the vscode json settings.

To do that Press F2 or Ctrl+Shift+P to open the vscode command palette
([command palette screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/883Nz.png))

then you have to write this:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
{ //exit insert mode
  "before": [
    "j",
    "k"
  ],
  "after": [
    "<Esc>"
  ]
}]
```

This code is mapping jk as `<Esc>`.
For more info on what settings the vim extension exposes, check out the [documentation on github](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim).

Comment: is there a way to make the mapping holding j+k to Esc or it can't be handled by keyboard technology? Now I press one after the other and it Escapes.. I guess it is not usual to have jk in a word but I am curious